# Is there a way to run portion of script by toggling via Xpath to JMeter script

Tags: xpath, jmeter

Is there a way to run portion of script by toggling via Xpathto JMeter script like as below

```
*/[@testname="...." and @enabled="true"]
```

I know from the GUI we can do, by adding the If controller for the samplers which we would like turn off .For ex: `${Enter_shift_hours} == ${ToTurnOff_EnterShiftHours}`

But If want to turn Off and On multiple actions , either i have to move under one If controller or create bunch of controllers to the associated ,so instead of going back and fourth to GUI script and update it ,Is there any way to toggle via Xpath to JMeter script.

Let's say Transaction Controller name is  : TimeCardSave_SelectProject and the Transaction has bunch of samplers TimeCardSave_SelectProject_${URL} .Now i would like to turn off the these samplers by toggling into JMX/XML script via Xpath

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for your JMeter test, it [provides simple way of enabling/disabling certain sections of the test using simple YAML syntax](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts)

```
---
execution:
  scenario:
    script: test.jmx
    modifications:
      disable:  # Names of the tree elements to disable
      - TimeCardSave_SelectProject_${URL}
```

More information: [Taurus: A New Star in the Test Automation Tools Constellation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation)

Comment: Besides Taurus what’s the  other option? Can it be done using functions?